# Css not working with FastCGI and Lighttpd

Tags: django, fastcgi, lighttpd, mod-fastcgi

Im new to fastcgi and lighttpd and trying to setup my DJANGO app. facing couple of problems at the moment:

1. CSS not working at all
2. FastCGI is adding its prefix for the requested URL i.e.
   mydomain.com/mysite.fcgi/mysite.fcgi/content/1/000228/ instead of
   mydomain.com/content/1/000228/

Below is my FastCGI script(10-fastcgi.conf) in conf-enabled folder:

```
# /usr/share/doc/lighttpd-doc/fastcgi.txt.gz
# http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ConfigurationOptions#mod_     
#  fastcgi-fastcgi

server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

fastcgi.server = (

"/" => (
    "main" => (

            "socket" => "/tmp/mysite.sock",
    "check-local" => "disable",
    )
),
)



alias.url = (
"/media" => "/home/path/to/my/media",
)

url.rewrite-once = (
"(/media.*)$" => "$1",
"^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
"^(/.*)$" => "/mysite.fcgi$1",
)

mimetype.assign = (
    ".html" => "text/html",
    ".txt" => "text/plain",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
    ".png" => "image/png",
    ".css" => "text/css"
 )
```

and my lighttpd.conf configuration:

```
server.modules = (
"mod_access",
"mod_alias",
"mod_compress",
"mod_redirect",
    "mod_rewrite",)

server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"

include "/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-fastcgi.conf"

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                            "index.htm", "default.htm",
                           " index.lighttpd.html" )

url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

dir-listing.encoding        = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing          = "enable"

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/x-javascript", "text/css", "text/html",    
                                "text/plain" )
```

Any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Here example of my conf.
Look at fastcgi.server values:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/django/example.com/mysite/"
    fastcgi.server = (
        "/mysite.fcgi" => (
            "main" => (
                # Use host / port instead of socket for TCP fastcgi
                # "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                # "port" => 3033,
                "socket" => "/var/django/example.com/mysite/mysite.sock",
                "check-local" => "disable",
                )
            ),
        )

    alias.url = (
        "/media" => "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/",
        "/favicon.ico" => "/var/django/example.com/mysite/static/img/favicon.ico",
    )

    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
        "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
        "^(/favicon.ico)$" => "$1",
        "^(/.*)$" => "/mysite.fcgi$1",
        )

    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/example.com.log"
```